# Attempt to use my singleton that references another singleton

Tags: c#

I'm calling my custom factory that I created (PhotoServiceFactory), which is a singleton that allows me to get at a specific custom service type back (in this case FacebookService).  FacebookService is also a singleton.  In FacebookService I've exposed an instance of FacebookAlbumPhoto through a property.  I did this because then I don't have to have a ton of the same code over and over again creating a new instance of FacebookAlbumPhoto...I can get an instance using the FacebookService's property.

```
PhotoServiceFactory service = PhotoServiceFactory.CurrentPhotoServiceFactory;
FacebookService facebookService = (FacebookService)service.GetAPIService(APIType.Facebook);

FacebookAlbumPhoto facebookPhoto = facebookService.FacebookAlbumPhoto.GetFacebookAlbumPhoto(selectedPhotoID);
```

So this is all set up now, I created all this and just testing it now.

**What's happening is my code is bombing out at this line:**

```
FacebookAlbumPhoto facebookPhoto = facebookService.FacebookAlbumPhoto.GetFacebookAlbumPhoto(selectedPhotoID);
```

**The error I get is when I try to reference the facebookService.*FacebookAlbumPhoto* instance:**

> CurrentSession = '_singletonInstance.CurrentSession' threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'

So I don't know if it's because the service singleton is on one thread and then it tries to reference another singleton that's on a completely different thread and that's just not possible?  That it's not possible to nest singletons like this?  Or could this be another issue altogether?  Cause I can't see it.

**Here's my ServiceFactory:**

```
public class PhotoServiceFactory
{
    private static PhotoServiceFactory _singletonInstance;
    private PhotoServiceFactory(){}

    public static PhotoServiceFactory CurrentPhotoServiceFactory
    {
        get
        {
            _singletonInstance = _singletonInstance ?? (_singletonInstance = new PhotoServiceFactory());
            return _singletonInstance;
        }
    }

    public object GetAPIService(APIType apiType)
    {
        object apiService = null;
        switch (apiType)
        {
            case APIType.Facebook:
                apiService = FacebookService.CurrentService;
                break;
            // rest of code
        }

        return apiService;
    }
```

**So the main singleton here Service has a property to get its related Session:**

Here's the FacebookServiceClass:

```
public class FacebookService
{
    private static FacebookService _singletonInstance;

    private FacebookService(){}

    public FacebookSession CurrentSession
    {
        get
        {
            return FacebookSession.GetCurrentSession();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current facebook service singleton instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current facebook service.</value>
    public static FacebookService CurrentService
    {
        get
        {
            _singletonInstance = _singletonInstance ?? (_singletonInstance = new FacebookService());
            return _singletonInstance;
        }
    }

    public FacebookAlbumPhoto FacebookAlbumPhoto
    {
        get
        {
            return new FacebookAlbumPhoto(); // create an instance automatically so we can start working with this object
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the session class:**

```
public class FacebookSession
{
    const string loginCallbackUrl = "http://localhost/PhotoUpload/FacebookOauth.aspx";

    private FacebookSession()
    {
    }

    public string UserID { get; private set; }

    public static FacebookSession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        //....bunch of other logic is here
        FacebookSession facebookSession = CreateNewSession();
        return facebookSession;
    }

    public FacebookSession CreateNewSession()
    {
        //...some code here
        FacebookSession newFacebookSession = new FacebookSession
        //... rest of code...
        return newFacebookSession;
    }
    // ... rest of code
}
```

**UPDATED:**

As requested here's my FacebookAlbumPhoto class that I created:

```
    public class FacebookAlbumPhoto : FacebookPhotoBase
    {
        private FacebookSession currentSession;

        public FacebookAlbumPhoto()
        {
            currentSession = FacebookService.CurrentService.CurrentSession;             
        }

        #region Methods

        public FacebookAlbumPhoto GetFacebookAlbumPhoto(string photoID)
        {
            ...more code
             FacebookPhotoRequest request = new FacebookPhotoRequest(currentSession.UserID, photoID);
            ...more code

            FacebookAlbumPhoto facebookPhoto = ParseFacebookPhoto(json);

            return facebookPhoto;
        }
...rest of code
}
```

Comment: I've tried to "tidy-up" your code snippets a little, removing `#region`s and prefixing comments with `//` to try and make it a bit easier to read as there's quite a lot of code there =).

Comment: Also, you haven't included the code for `FacebookAlbumPhoto` which would be useful as the error is occuring in `GetFacebookAlbumPhoto(selectedPhotoID)` or the constructor for FacebookAlbumPhoto, neither of which is available for review at present...

Comment: well I'm not sure that the error is happening in that class because it's not hitting any debug points I set in GetFacebookAlbumPhoto which is why this is such a mystery to me...I get to break points up to the FacebookService and Session but then when it goes to try and use that FacebookAlbumPhoto instance (the instance that I intend on getting from the FacebookService's property) it is calling some code that I guess I don't have debug points on but I see absolutely nowhere else it could be running code from so it's very weird.

Comment: I mean is it weird that I'm trying to set a variable of type FacebookAlbumPhoto by use a property of my service where that property spawns a new instance of FacebookAlbumPhoto in order for me to call FacebookAlbumPhoto.GetFacebookAlbumPhoto which returns a FacebookAlbumPhoto lol? I don't want to make FacebookAlbumPhoto a static class or GetFacebookAlbumPhoto a static method so...to me this is easy..I can instantiate the FacebookAlbumPhoto class through that service property in order to call GetFacebookAlbumPhoto() to set my FacebookAlbumPhoto variable. I don't know, is this bad?

Comment: talking about this line from the last reply: 

FacebookAlbumPhoto facebookPhoto = facebookService.FacebookAlbumPhoto.GetFacebookAlbumPhoto(selectedPhotoID); 

I just thought it would be a nice convenience member of the service class for it to spawn a new instance of whatever classes I need to use...in this example being FacebookAlbumPhoto.  I'll have others later in that FacebookService class as well such as a FacebookAlbum property, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.  First, remember to read over [Skeet's catalogue of singleton implementations](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).
Second, try breaking your code just before the spot where the exception occurs, and then bring up your "Exception" dialogue (ctrl-alt-e).  Click the "throw" checkbox next to the CLR (second row of dialogue) and hit ok.  Continue debugging your code.  The results may tell you where the real problem is.

Don't forgot to go back to the Exception dialogue and remove that check from the check box, after you are done. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped because I had put a debug point and tried to F11 all the way through but it still wasn't showing me before, where it was last bombing out.  Using this, I was able to see it where F11 failed to show me. I found that I had not set a breakpoint at the return new FacebookAlbumPhoto(); code in the property of my FacebookService.  It's bombing out there.

Comment: So I wonder when I am trying to use that property like this, that you can't just start using that property like that?  FacebookAlbumPhoto facebookPhoto = facebookService.FacebookAlbumPhoto.GetFacebookAlbumPhoto(selectedPhotoID);  So it's bailing at the FacebookAlbumPhoto property of my facebookService object.  I just have a return new FacebookAlbumPhoto in that property in my get.  Then immediately put a dot right after to try and use that property which is sending me back an instance of FacebookAlbumPhoto..see above.

Comment: I also noticed that I get a thread abort exception in my FacebookAlbumPhoto's constructor when I try to get the CurrentService from my FacebookService class...that line you see above.

Comment: Something about this problem keeps telling me that you should fix your singleton, so that it matches Skeet's code. In other words, don't do this: _singletonInstance = _singletonInstance ?? (_singletonInstance = new FacebookService());

Comment: (continued) even if you did do that, it would still be better as: _singinstance = singinstance ?? new FacebookService();  But as I said, try a formal singleton approach first.

Comment: oh I thought that was a pretty standard singleton setup...I've used this before.

Comment: thanks it was indeed how I setup the check for null here:                 _singletonInstance = _singletonInstance ?? (_singletonInstance = new FacebookService());
 so I changed it to return _singletonInstance ?? new FacebookService();  However I don't like to return an expression like that.  I like to shove it into a variable first for debugging purposes then return the variable.  I guess I can still do that.

Answer (score 0):

separate instance creation from initialization